# Download start & download end events in inno

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

Is there a way to address the following events  - 
**1. when IDP  started to download a file?
2. when IDP Finished to download a file?**

I wish to send an HTTP request on the above events, please help

*IDP - inno download plugin

Comment: So you want to download a file when IDP starts downloading a file?

Comment: I want to send HTTP request when a download starts and when it ends

Comment: A download is an HTTP request. Why not just add it as another file to download before/after, or a call to `idpDownloadFile()` either side?